# Magento Remove attribute filter from a category

Tags: magento, filter, attributes, categories

i have this request:

It's possible to remove a filterable attribute from a category?

Example i have 2 item with 2 attribute set.
One item is in category A the other is in category B

this two products have one attribute in common in the attribute set, example Color.

i want that the filter on Color attribute appear for category A and not for category B.

i need to split the attribute (example color_a, color_b) and make one filterable and the other none? or there is a solution to set only one attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have look around a lot with no solution.
We have implement an extension to do that, it's the only solution found.